# How to SetAdapter on Firebase recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a movie app in which a list item called "Now showing" would open up a new activity to load a list of movies that are taken from my firebase database of movies. However, when I press "now showing", the app will crash.
This is my codes

```
public class NowShowing extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView movieRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase movieFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference moviesRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_now_showing);
            //recyclerview
        movieRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listnowshowingmovies);
        movieRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        movieRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
            //send query to Firebasedatabase
        movieFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        moviesRef = movieFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
    }
    //load data into recyclerview onstart
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions <movies> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<movies>().setQuery(moviesRef, movies.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<movies, ViewHolder>( options ) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movies_cardview_all,parent,false);

            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull movies model) {

            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getMovieTitle(),model.getMovieThumbnail(),model.getMovieSynopsis(),model.getMovieReleaseDate(),model.getMovieGenre(),
                    model.getMovieCast(),model.getMovieAgeRestriction(),model.getMovieRating());
        }
    };
}
```

This is the Error I get

> ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ethan.premovies/com.example.ethan.premovies.NowShowing}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.ethan.premovies.NowShowing.onCreate(NowShowing.java:30)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

I AM DESPERATELY IN NEED OF HELP BECAUSE I STILL NEED TO MAKE A REVIEW PAGE. I am only a beginner and i just got to know this. My school is not bothered to teach us this so i had to find out myself. I am seeking some people to coach me for Firebase as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
movieRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

adapter is null when this is called.
It needs instantiated with the info that FirebaseRecyclerAdapter will provide, but from the code provided it looks like adapter is created after you're trying to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RecyclerView movieRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase movieFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference moviesRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_now_showing);
        //recyclerview
    movieRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listnowshowingmovies);
    movieRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    movieRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
        //send query to Firebasedatabase
    movieFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    moviesRef = movieFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

    //load data into recyclerview in onCreate
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions <movies> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<movies>().setQuery(moviesRef, movies.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<movies, ViewHolder>( options ) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movies_cardview_all,parent,false);

            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull movies model) {

            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getMovieTitle(),model.getMovieThumbnail(),model.getMovieSynopsis(),model.getMovieReleaseDate(),model.getMovieGenre(),

            model.getMovieCast(),model.getMovieAgeRestriction(),model.getMovieRating());
        }
    });
}
```

Move the code in onCreate() as done above.